# Need to extract keys from json and store in in a file.New to jmeter.Also the keys are dynamic.Used json jmes extrac need to store the result to a file

Tags: json, jmeter

```
{ 
    "csncnjcnsd-nvkmckmdks-930vbc":{}
    "jvjdhjcsicn-bunwnc-nvn5477":{}
}
```

I am able to see the above ids with jmeter properties in response body of debug sampler but i need to store it into a xlsx file for further use.Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Do you want to save 2 key ‘csncn…930vbc’ and ‘jvjdh…5477’ to a xlsx file? Can use txt or csv instead?

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 yes need to extract those keys .okay with using either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSR223 PostProcessor like this:

```
def keys = "";
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).eachWithIndex{ def node, int idx ->
    keys = keys + node.getKey() + "\r\n"
}
//Will save file to folder jmeter bin
def file1 = new File('response.txt')

file1.write(keys.toString())
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked .Could you suggest any resources to read about groovy and jsr233 postprocessor

Comment: @KshitijaPatil you can start here https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter

Comment: if i want to put a variable name to this column how can i make changes to this code like a parameter

Comment: You can do this: `def keys = "var_name"+"\r\n"`

Comment: I have a question in case i want to run this thread group under another thread what could be the possible way to do this heres the question link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469959/is-it-possible-to-write-a-thread-under-a-thread-in-jmeter-if-yes-then-how/69470187#69470187

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store the values into the .CSV file - you can use [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property and the [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin)

If the file has to be "xlsx" - you will need to have [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) libraries in the [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and write the code in the suitable [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), here is an example:

```
def workbook = new org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook();
def sheet = workbook.createSheet('Sheet1');
def row = sheet.createRow(0);
def cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(vars.get('your_variable_name_here'))
workbook.write(new File('your-filename-here.xlsx'))
```

Comment: beanshell scripting in this case wont prove useful right?

Comment: You can use Beanshell if you want, in general [Groovy has much better performance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), but given you will be writing in a file with only 1 thread at a time it shouldn't be a problem.