# Is it possible to write a thread under a thread in jmeter ?If yes then how?

Tags: jmeter

```
-Thread
  -thread
```

planning to feed a csv data set with user and log in info and try to run internal thread for all the ids in for every row of data in upper thread

Comment: So basically, you want to each user (in one csv) will make a request with each job_id (in another csv)?

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 first csv will contain lots of users and every user should be able to make a request to all job_ids in the next csv

Comment: So first thread grp will have csv of users and the thread group inside it (sub-thread grp)will have csv of all job_ids

Comment: I think you're overthinking. I will make an attemp to solve this.

Comment: I found the same question as yours, check it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370585/loop-on-user-csv-and-then-loop-on-data-csv-in-jmeter it's also Dmitri's answer. He's an expert in jmeter and perf test.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see why would you need an "internal thread" for this but if you have to - go for the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller)

Parallel Controller spawns a brand new thread for each child element of it, if you want to iterate all the values in the CSV file in that new thread you could go for something like:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the Parallel Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

Comment: The case is I have a set of users in a file .And in the second file I have a set of job id. I want to check for every line of user job id in the second csv file.I am trying to find out the best and easiest way to do that